# How to avoid Back button to crash the APP on React Native

Tags: react-native

I working on a React Native App and implemented a BackAndroid component. In order to switch between scenes, I'm using a navigator.jumpTo(route).

The BackAndroid component works fine until I reach the Home (first route), so, if I hit the back button again my app crashes and shows me an error "Cannot back before the first route".

In order to solve this, I'm using a try statement, but I don't think this is an elegant solution. I was thinking in a way of detect the route or something like that.

Appreciate any help.

Here is my code:

```
handlesBackButton() {
  if (
    this._navigator
    && this._navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1
  ) {
      try {
        this._navigator.jumpBack();
      } catch(e) {}
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

componentWillMount() {
  BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',this.handlesBackButton);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handlesBackButton);
}
```